# Sending JobID parameter from email to landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I am trying to send the `jobid` from an email to a landing page with the use of `%%jobid%%`, and store it there (in the landing page) in an Ampscript variable.

```
<a target="_blank" title="" href="%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(1234,"jobid",%%jobid%%))=%%">Click</a>
```

What do I put on the landing page to fetch the ID and store it an ampscript variable?

I tried this with no luck:

```
set @jobid = RequestParameter("jobid")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that `%%jobid%%` doesn't work inside an AMPscript block or expression. You need to use `AttributeValue('jobid')` instead.

So the code for your link would look like this:

```html
<a target="_blank" title="" href="%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(1234, 'jobid', AttributeValue('jobid')))=%%">Click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! On the landing page I have set `@jobid = RequestParameter("jobid")`, however I am not able to print the value (just gives me a blank value). Do you know what could be wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you check if the URL contains the jobid or if there is a problem on the email side? Maybe try omitting the `RedirectTo` as it shouldn't be necessary if you don't need tracking right now.

Comment: Unfortunately still not able to print the value. I think it must be a problem on the email side then! Will accept solution :)

Answer (score 0):

@apples-oranges use like this in email `<a target="_blank" title="" href="%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(1234, 'jobid', AttributeValue('jobid')))=%%">Click</a>` and in landing page use this one `%%[
set @jobid = RequestParameter('jobid')
]%%
jobid:%%=v(@jobid)=%% its passing jobid from email to landing page`

Comment: How does this differ from the solution I proposed more than an hour before your answer?

Comment: @ Markus Slabina  both are same but in landing page he is not displaying the job id